# Rspec - capture stderr output of linux process

Tags: ruby, rspec, stderr

I want to test what my bash script output some message to stderr.
I try this:

```
require 'rspec'

describe 'My behaviour' do

  it 'should do something' do
    expect { `echo "foo" 1>&2` }.to output.to_stderr
  end
end
```

But seems output to stderr happened not during test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a less precise, but more easier to read method:

```
require 'rspec'

describe 'My behaviour' do

  it 'should do something' do
    expect { system('echo "foo" 1>&2 ') }.to output.to_stderr_from_any_process
  end
end
```

AFAIU - it cannot check exact message, but it's enough for me

Comment: You can check the exact message: `.to output('foo').to_std_error_from_any_process` -- [read the docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher#output-to-stderr-from-any-process-matcher)

Answer (score 3):

RSpec's `output.to_stderr` matcher is looking for things that write to `$stdout`/`$stderr` -- which your shell command is not doing, as it runs as a separate sub-process.

In order to test this, you need to explicitly capture the `stdout` and `stderr` of the shell code. You could build your own implementation of this quite easily using the [`Open3` standard library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html), or for example use the [`rspec-bash` gem](https://github.com/mdurban/rspec-bash):

```
require 'rspec'
require 'rspec/bash'

describe 'My behaviour' do
  include Rspec::Bash

  let(:stubbed_env) { create_stubbed_env }

  it 'should do something' do
    stdout, stderr, status = stubbed_env.execute(
      'echo "foo" 1>&2'
    )
    expect(stderr).to eq('foo')
  end
end
```